# With multiple ingress controllers - Is it possible to have a "default" one?

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, traefik-ingress

On my cluster I use `traefik` as an ingress-controller, but now also want to provide an `nginx` controller.

I don't want my developers to think about how exactly their application is exposed. Therefore I would like to make traefik the "default" controller and only use nginx if the developer explicitly requests that controller by setting the proper `ingress.class`.

Unfortunately it looks like setting *no* class will result in both controllers fighting about that ingress. :(
Is there a way to tell a controller to *only* handle a ingress object if has the correct `ingress.class`?

If that is not possible, I was thinking about writing a MutatingAdmissionWebhook which will insert the traefik class in case no class is set. - Does this make sense, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handling `no class` is an arbitrary ingress implementation decision. 
You typically pass the desired class into a binary and it then filters all the config map events with a corresponding class: 
https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/nginx-ingress/templates/controller-deployment.yaml#L60

As far as I know, no one does `no class`, nor do I recommend as it would be error-prone. Someone will forget to add class and will implicitly get exposed where they did not want.

Mutating hook is a way to go, as it will add an explicit note of what ingress this belongs to. Try https://github.com/HotelsDotCom/kube-graffiti

The simplest way will be just to register traefik to listen on `ingress.class: default` or `dev` and ask developers to put this in all their templates. In this way, you will abstract them from a particular ingress choice underneath.